# How to crawl links from a database of a website?

Tags: php, mysql, web-crawler

I am new to search engines, and I find googlenews very interesting.

I would like to write a simple crawler which

1. parse only the article links of three different news sites.
2. Save the links in database (mysql) with the timestamp in which the link has been advertised on the website (not the time in which the link has been detected by the crawler).

As you know, news website generate links on a daily basis (And I would like basically to parse all their links (not just those who are printed today, but also all the links that were generated before...and all these links are kept in the news website database).

I dont know which database is used by the news websites that I want to crawl and I also don`t have access permission to it.

1. So how does googlenews able to parse all the article links of all news sites, including the links which have been generated long time ago? Does googlenews have access to all those websites databases?
2. How does a crawler know that a NEW link has been added to the website? if for example, a news site posted a new article, and I want my crawler to parse the link immediately, how can the crawler knows that (googlenews also able to do it...so how...?) i.e does the crawler knows immediately about the new article link? or google just crawls the website on a fixed interval (every one hour etc...)?
3. How does google news crawler know when a new website has been launched? 
   Does the crawler looks automatically for new websites, or google engineers basically holds a fixed list of news website to crawl?

The same question can be asked regarding google search crawler i.e crawler should be aware that a new domain has been launched so it can crawl it and therefore make sure google database reflect the most updated state of the world wide web.

So is there any open worldwide database which keeps all the domains ever launched and google basically crawls it?

1. What will be the best tool to implement my news website crawler?

Apache Lucene, Nutch, Solr, ElasticSearch?

Maybe http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/?

I am REALLY curious to the answer of the above four questions.

Please assist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: most of Google will not allow you to crawl it. They have a lot of 'anti crawl code' technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some key questions here which I'll answer but first you should understand what is a crawler.

**What is a crawler?**

The crawler's job is to scan the internet by reading a page, getting all the links he contains and then reading those pages as well. The main purpose of this action is to find new content automatically. A good crawler will start crawling few big and familiar websites that updates often, this way he can update and index these sites and also get new content and new sites fast (because big websites often contains links to other sites).

Regarding your questions:

> Does googlenews have access to all those websites databases?

**No**, if you got access to the database there is no need for a crawler.

> How does a crawler know that a NEW link has been added to the website?

Google crawls every site once in a while and searches for new links inside the site. Usually a new page or an article will be linked through the main page that already stored in Google's database.

> How does google news crawler know when a new website has been
>   launched?

The simple answer is: the crawler finds a link to the new website, checks if the website is in the system and if not, adds it.

> How they get the links of the old articles?

Easy, they save those links in a huge database. Google started crawling the internet years ago. Old links probably won't show up if Google will start crawling the internet today all over again.

> How do I get the timing in which the site posted the article?

That's depends on the site you're crawling. If each article have a date you need to parse the page and extract this date. [This article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-27742899) have a date in the top and it's easy to find the the HTML dom by searching the date class: `<span class="date">6 June 2014</span>`.
If the date does not appear, you won't have a way to know when they published it.

As a developer you can make the life of Google easier and ask Google to crawl your new website via [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en).

While crawling the web, Google also counts how many links lead to a page, this will affect the page's ranking. Many links to your site will indicate you have a valuable content and you should appear higher in the search results.

Writing a simple crawler is easy. You get a page's content with `php cURL` or `file_get_contents`, parse it, select and save the data you want, extract all the links in this page and then recursively crawl the links you found.